# Check if object is in a list of objects

Tags: powershell

As PowerShell has many SQL query-like cmdlets, is there a fast way to check if object is in list of other objects with the `Where-Object` cmdlet?

Something like in SQL:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

Of course I can write a simple subroutine, but I was just wondering if there is such feature.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `-contains` operator:

```
Get-ColumnNames $table | Where-Object { value1,value2,... -contains $_ }
```

It's backwards, though with the collection of values on the left side.

In PowerShell 3 you can also use the `-in` operator:

```
Where-Object { $_ -in value1,value2,... }
```

or even

```
Where-Object -In value1,value2,...
```

Also, a quirk of how PowerShell works with comparison operators, you can apply them directly to a collection on the left side:

```
Where-Object { value1,value2,... -eq $_ }
```

The `-eq` operator here will either yield the respective element if it is in the list, or `$null` (which coerces to `$false`).